# How to combine the values of Pandas dataframe rows by a shared attribute in another column? And produce a new column with this concatenated?

Tags: python, pandas

I am compiling a 'colleague award' list at my place of work. Members of staff can nominate as many colleagues as they like. What I would like is to produce a 'mail merge' style output where each staff member gets a list of their comments and who left them.

I have a .csv file which consists of 'Name' (of the person nominating), 'Who' (the person being nominated) and 'Why' (the comment).

How can I use PANDAS to combine the rows of the df by the common value, which is who the comment is about, and concatenate these together with who said it, into a new column in the DF with this info.

Code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Colleague Award 2023(1-296).csv')

df2 = df.drop(['ID', 'Start time' , 'Completion time', 'Email'], axis = 1)
df3 = df2.sort_values('Who', ascending=True)

df4 = df3.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).agg({'Why' : ' '.join})

df4.to_csv('Colleage Award Collated.csv')
```

My output is just the 'why' strings stuck together and the 'who' column has been omitted.

EDIT/Update:
What I am really after is to write to a csv where the columns are like this:

| Who | Why |
| --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | Jane Doe: Joe is super helpful |
|  | Gary Public: Joe always makes good coffee |
| Jane Doe | Joe Bloggs: Jane is a friendly face in the morning |
|  | Gary Public: Jane makes my day better! |
| Jimmy Person | Jane Doe: Jimmy helps us out with our IT issues! |

But where all comments are in the same cell, not seperated

This is so I can then easily do a mail-merge and create many word documents, one for each recipient with all of their comments from various colleagues.

Thank you again to those who have already contributed!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this input format:

```
          Name          Who                               Why
0   Joe Bloggs     Jane Doe              Joe is super helpful
1   Joe Bloggs  Gary Public  Joe always brings my good coffee
2  Gary Public     Jane Doe   Gary always helps me with my PC
3  Gary Public   Joe Bloggs   Thank you Gary for training me!
```

You can use a loop with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
sep = ''
for name, g in df.groupby('Name', sort=False):
    if sep:
        print(sep)
    sep = 'NEW ROW'
    print(f'{name} your comments:')
    for who, why in zip(g['Who'], g['Why']):
        print(f'{who}: {why}')
```

Output:

```
Joe Bloggs your comments:
Jane Doe: Joe is super helpful
Gary Public: Joe always brings my good coffee
NEW ROW
Gary Public your comments:
Jane Doe: Gary always helps me with my PC
Joe Bloggs: Thank you Gary for training me!
```

##### output as DataFrame

To create a new DataFrame:

```
out = df.assign(
          Why=lambda d: d['Who']+': '+d['Why'],
          Name=lambda d: d['Name'].mask(d['Name'].duplicated(), '')
         )[['Name', 'Why']]
```

To modify the input DataFrame in place:

```
df['Why'] = df.pop('Who')+': '+df['Why']
df.loc[df['Name'].duplicated(), 'Name'] = ''
```

Output:

```
          Name                                            Why
0   Joe Bloggs                 Jane Doe: Joe is super helpful
1               Gary Public: Joe always brings my good coffee
2  Gary Public      Jane Doe: Gary always helps me with my PC
3                 Joe Bloggs: Thank you Gary for training me!
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much. How would I add these into a new column? I want to be able to export to excel and then use in a mail-merge to produce lots of word docs to email out.

Comment: @JamChart what would be the output format as "new column"? Please provide an edit to your question

Comment: Thanks, I have provided an update with what I am after, thanks so much!

Comment: OK, see update, using the same input

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update, its nearly perfect, how do I get all comments in the same row? When I export to CSV, I get the successive comments for the same person in separate rows.

Comment: Then `df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda g: '\n'.join(g['Who']+': '+g['Why'])).reset_index(name='Why')`? It would be more explicit to provide a reproducible format for the input/output (as code, not tables)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired output, you can modify your code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Colleague Award 2023(1-296).csv')

df2 = df.drop(['ID', 'Start time', 'Completion time', 'Email'], axis=1)
df3 = df2.sort_values('Who', ascending=True)

df4 = df3.groupby(['Who'], as_index=False).agg({'Name': ' '.join, 'Why': lambda x: '\n'.join(x)})
df4['Comments'] = df4['Name'] + ': ' + df4['Why']
df4 = df4[['Who', 'Comments']]

df4.to_csv('Colleague Award Collated.csv', index=False)
```

The output file (Colleague Award Collated.csv) generated by the updated code will have two columns: 'Who' and 'Comments'. Each row represents a person being nominated, and the corresponding comments will be concatenated in the 'Comments' column, including the names of the nominators.